# При объединении gulpом css файлов, заменяет ссылки на border-image

Tags: css, gulp

до объединения

```
shapka {
    border-image-source: url(img/shapka.png);    
}
```

и после

```
shapka {
  border-image-source: url("../../../../src/css/img/shapka.png");

}
```

как получить такой путь?

```
shapka {
      border-image-source: url("../../src/css/img/shapka.png");

    }
```

или сделать чтобы ссылку не трогал при объединении?

gulpfile

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
    rigger = require('gulp-rigger');
    concat = require('gulp-concat');
    concatCss = require('gulp-concat-css');
    cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
    watch = require('gulp-watch');
    browserSync = require('browser-sync');

var path = {
    build: {
        html: 'build/',
        css: 'build/css',
        js: 'build/js'
    }, 
    src: {
        html: 'src/*.html',
        css: 'src/css/*.css', 
        js: 'src/js/*.js'        
    },
    watch: {
        html: 'src/**/*.html',
        css: 'src/css/*.css',
        js: 'src/js/*.js'
    }
};

gulp.task('default', ["build", "webserver", "watch"]);

gulp.task('build', ["build:html", "build:js", "build:css"]);

gulp.task('build:html', function () {
    gulp.src(path.src.html)
        .pipe(rigger())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.html));
}); 

gulp.task('build:js', function() {
    gulp.src(['bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js', 'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', path.src.js])
        .pipe(concat('main.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.js));
});

gulp.task('build:css', function() {
    gulp.src(['bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css', path.src.css])
        .pipe(cleanCSS({compatibility: 'ie8'}))
        .pipe(concatCss("main.css"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.css));
});

gulp.task('webserver', function () {
    var files = [
        'build/*.html',
        'build/css/*.css',
        'build/js/*.js'
    ];

    browserSync.init(files, {
        server: {
            baseDir: 'build'
        }
    });
});

gulp.task('watch', function() { 
    watch([path.watch.html, path.watch.css, path.watch.js], function(event, cb) {
        gulp.start('build');
    });
});
```

Comment: Покажите ваш gulpfile.js

Comment: @shugich gulpfile.js добавлен

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно сделать, чтобы не трогал ссылки:

```
gulp.task('build:css', function() {
    gulp.src(['./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css', path.src.css])
        .pipe(cleanCSS({
            compatibility: 'ie8'
        }))
        .pipe(concatCss("main.css", {
            rebaseUrls: false
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.css));
});
```